# how to analysis local project through remote server in sonar lint

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1, sonarlint

I have project in my local machine but sonar server is on remote location. Is there  any way to analysis my local project with remote sonar server. 
I am using sonarLint plugin in my eclipse luna.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent versions of SonarLint do not rely on a SonarQube server. It works completely offline as it include all necessary analyzers and settings.

Soon, it will be possible to connect it to a SonarQube server to use information from it, for example, quality profiles and resolved issues.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am getting  below error to install plugin in  eclipse luna:  . org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf
Error
Fri Feb 19 13:24:04 IST 2016
Unable to read repository at https://sonarsource.bintray.com/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/1.0.0/content.xml.

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
 at

Comment: Try to install it offline using the file here: https://bintray.com/sonarsource/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/_latestVersion

Comment: Ok thaks one more issue sir, I have SonarQube 3.5 version here i want to analysis my local project with remote sonar server. what are the steps for it